# Should I use "although", "though", or "even though" in the following case?

Tags: word-choice

> That would be odd because, **although/though/even though** we knew about the place, we’d
>   never been there.

What's the correct choice here? And why?

Comment: Never use "alhought" ... but *although* or *even though* are fine. The bare *though* would sound unusual there, though it would not be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an English native speaker, but considering your sentence, it would sound odd or unusual to hear **though**.

I would say that you should use only **although** or **even though**.

If you want to use **though**, your sentence should be different, like:

> **Though** we knew about the place, that would be odd because we'd never
>   been there.

I could be wrong **though**. :-)

Answer (score 0):

"Though" and "although" are two conjunctions that can be usually used interchangeably, and "even though" is generally considered a stronger or more emphatic way to express the contrast compared to using just "though" or "although".

Then all three choices are correct in terms of the structure of the sentence.

### References

1. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/even%20though
2. https://www.englishgrammar.org/spite-grammar-exercise-2/